# What is the code to skip or replace the existing data in the sheet being added?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code of adding a sheet in multiple workbooks. I want to know how to skip or replace the exiting data in those multiple workbooks.

```
Sub AddingChklist()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Dim path As String
    Dim file As String
    Dim Chklist As Workbook
    path = "C:\Users\Documents\Macro Project\"
    file = Dir(path)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While Not file = ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & file)
        Set Chklist = ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Recon Checklist"
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recon Checklist").Range("A1:C25").Copy Destination:=Chklist.Sheets("Recon Checklist").Range("A1")
        Range("A1:C25").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("A1:C25").EntireRow.AutoFit
        Chklist.Save
        Chklist.Close
        file = Dir
     Loop
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Checklist has been added to all the files"

End Sub
```

Copied from discussion below:-
My question was if the recon checklist sheet was already in one of the workbooks while running this macro. How we need to skip or replace the existing sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.  In order to do away with the heavy flicker connected with opening many files in succession this procedure creates an invisible instance of Excel dedicated to this task. While this works very smoothly, it unfortunately raises the problem of not being able to copy formatting from one instance of Excel to another. Therefore my code only copies values. However, you have full access to each new sheet. For now only `AutoFit` is applied but you could do a lot of more formatting at that point if you feel the need.

```
Sub AddingChklist()
    ' 242
    
    Const WsName    As String = "Recon Checklist"   ' Ws actual name
    
    Dim Xl          As New Excel.Application    ' dedicated instance of Excel
    Dim ChkList     As Variant                  ' Checklist
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim File        As String
    Dim Sp()        As String                   ' split of File
    Dim Wb          As Workbook                 ' loop object
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet                ' loop object: CheckList
    
    Xl.Visible = True                          ' hide the newly opened workbooks
    Path = "C:\Users\Documents\Macro Project\"
    ChkList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WsName).Range("A1:C25").Value

    File = Dir(Path)
    Do While Not File = ""
        Sp = Split(File, ".")                   ' process only Excel workbooks
        If InStr(1, Sp(UBound(Sp)), "xls", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            Set Wb = Xl.Workbooks.Open(Path & File)
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & Wb.Name
            
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets(WsName)
            If Err.Number = 9 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Set Ws = Wb.Sheets.Add(Before:=Wb.Sheets(1))
                Ws.Name = WsName
            End If
            
            With Ws
                .Cells.ClearContents
                .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(ChkList), UBound(ChkList, 2)).Value = ChkList
                .Columns.AutoFit
                .Rows.AutoFit
            End With
            
            Wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
        File = Dir
     Loop
    
    Xl.Quit                                     ' close the dedicated instance of Excel
'    MsgBox "Checklist has been added to all the files"
    Application.StatusBar = "Checklist has been added to all the files"
End Sub
```

Observe that the code first looks for an existing tab by the same name. If such a sheet doesn't exist it will be created. Any existing sheet will be wiped clean. Finally, the contents of your template will be pasted to the new/clean sheet.

Note that I added a test to the code to ensure that only Excel workbooks will be processed.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. My question was if the recon checklist sheet was already in one of the workbooks while running this macro. How we need to skip or replace the existing sheet.

Comment: No, my friend, you most certainly did ***not*** ask that question. But I understand now what you want and have modified my answer accordingly.